# c - const char* and char* casting (ADPCM decoding)

Tags: c, char, constants, exc-bad-access, short

Here is the objective-c sister question, which might provide some insight:
[c and objective-c -- const char* and char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883503/c-and-objective-c-const-char-and-char)

I am doing the following:

```
g_ADPCMstate.valprev=32767;
g_ADPCMstate.index=0;


const char *modulatedBytes1 = {0xca,0x82,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80};
char *modulatedBytes =  (char *)modulatedBytes1;
unsigned int moduleatedLength = 8;
short *decompressedBytes = NULL;

adpcm_decoder(modulatedBytes, decompressedBytes, moduleatedLength, &g_ADPCMstate);
```

The function declaration is:

```
void      
adpcm_decoder(indata, outdata, len, state)      
    char indata[];      
    short outdata[];      
    int len;      
    struct adpcm_state *state;
```

`g_ADPCMstate` is the global instance variable for a adpcm_state struct. http://codepad.org/5vyd0CXA is the full code. The function crashes when  `*outp++ = valprev;` happens and I get a BAD ACCESS statement from my debugger. outp is a pointer to outData while valprev is a long.

The problem has to be in my understanding of pointers and either `modulatedBytes` and/or `decompressedBytes`

I have little understanding of C and lower level concepts. I would love some insight into my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `short *decompressedBytes = NULL;` as the `outdata` argument to `adpcm_decoder()`, and then try to dereference it.  Did you forget to allocate `decompressedBytes`?

Comment: what should I allocate it as? Should I store random bits in it?

Comment: @stackOverFlew Just allocate it using `malloc()`, and then let `adpcm_decoder` take care of initializing it (via the line `*outp++ = valprev`).